# Android RTP Audio Streaming hearing Disturbing sound

Tags: android, audio, streaming, rtp

I'm developing a VOIP application, voice call connecting successfully. After the voice call answer other side hearing some disturbing sound.
Below are my RTP convert code, I'm using PCMA 8000. Anyone knows how to fix this?

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Random;

public class RTPPacketCreator {


    Random random = new Random();
    int ssrc = random.nextInt();
    short sequenceNumber = 0;
    private static final int RTP_HEADER_SIZE = 12;
    public byte[]  encode(byte[] audioData){
    int packetSize = RTP_HEADER_SIZE + audioData.length;
    ByteBuffer rtpBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(packetSize);

    // Generate RTP header fields
    byte version = 2;
    byte padding = 0;
    byte extension = 0;
    byte marker = 0;
    byte payloadType = 8; // PCMU payload type is typically 0 for RTP


    // Set the RTP version, padding, extension, and marker fields
    rtpBuffer.put((byte) ((version << 6) | (padding << 5) | (extension << 4) | (marker << 7)));

    // Set the payload type field
    rtpBuffer.put(payloadType);

    // Set the sequence number field (increment for each packet)
    // Set the initial sequence number
    rtpBuffer.putShort(sequenceNumber);

    // Set the timestamp field (use appropriate value based on the sample rate)
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Use the current time as the timestamp
    rtpBuffer.putInt((int) timestamp);

    // Set the SSRC field
    rtpBuffer.putInt(ssrc);

    // Set the audio data (payload)
    rtpBuffer.put(audioData);

    // Flip the buffer to prepare for reading
    rtpBuffer.flip();
    sequenceNumber++;
    if (sequenceNumber > 65535) {
        sequenceNumber = 0;
    }
    return rtpBuffer.array();
    // Now you can use the RTP packet ByteBuffer for further processing, such as sending it over the network or handling it in your application

   }
}
```